# Leaked window when exit app through (popup) menu

Tags: android, drop-down-menu, menu

I hope you can help me, I have a **leaked window** as soon as I **exit my application via the (popup) menu option** in the toolbar.
If I exit the app through a normal method everything is fine.

Could somebody maybe help? I cannot seem to find the error and I am trying to find a proper solution.
I have 2 static String variables declared but that cannot be the problem I guess.

Many thx in advance.

Here is the relevant code for the menu:

```
public class LoginActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
//
private Object mState = null;
private Object HIDE_MENU = null;
//
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
//
 @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {

        // inflate menu from xml
        MenuInflater mInflater = this.getMenuInflater();
        mInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);

        if (mState == HIDE_MENU) {
            menu.getItem(0).setVisible(false);
        }
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        switch (item.getItemId()) {

            case R.id.settings:
                    // Unassigned
                return true;

            case R.id.exit:
                    this.finish();
                return true;

            default:
                return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }
//
}
```

The Logcat:

```
E/WindowManager: android.view.WindowLeaked: Activity myapp.example.com.myapp.LoginActivity has leaked window android.widget.PopupWindow$PopupDecorView{1f4c330 V.E...... ........ 0,0-686,168} that was originally added here
at android.view.ViewRootImpl.<init>(ViewRootImpl.java:368)
at android.view.WindowManagerGlobal.addView(WindowManagerGlobal.java:299)
at android.view.WindowManagerImpl.addView(WindowManagerImpl.java:85)
at android.widget.PopupWindow.invokePopup(PopupWindow.java:1258)
at android.widget.PopupWindow.showAsDropDown(PopupWindow.java:1110)
at android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatPopupWindow.showAsDropDown(AppCompatPopupWindow.java:78)
at android.support.v4.widget.PopupWindowCompatKitKat.showAsDropDown(PopupWindowCompatKitKat.java:30)
at android.support.v4.widget.PopupWindowCompat$KitKatPopupWindowImpl.showAsDropDown(PopupWindowCompat.java:92)
at android.support.v4.widget.PopupWindowCompat.showAsDropDown(PopupWindowCompat.java:171)
at android.support.v7.widget.ListPopupWindow.show(ListPopupWindow.java:680)
at android.support.v7.view.menu.MenuPopupHelper.tryShow(MenuPopupHelper.java:163)
at android.support.v7.widget.ActionMenuPresenter$OpenOverflowRunnable.run(ActionMenuPresenter.java:781)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

**EDIT**, my menu xml

```
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="myapp.example.com.myapp.MainActivity">
    <item
        android:id="@+id/settings"
        android:title="Instellingen"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
    <item
        android:id="@+id/exit"
        android:title="Exit"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

**EDIT2**, I **solved** it myself by adding a slow delay in closing the app. Apparently the menu window doesn`t get a chance to properly close before the app is exited, what triggers the leak.
Probably there is a more convenient way but this works.

```
//
case R.id.exit:

       Handler handlerClose = new Handler();
       handlerClose.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
              public void run() {
                  finish();
                 }
              },300);
       return true;
//
```

Comment: Also in this case you can call `onBackPressed()` instead of finish()

Comment: I had a similar situation (using a Spinner in an ActionBar and using that to switch to another activity) and I too had to use a delay, closeOptionsMenu() would not work. Android 6. If you answer your own question (EDIT2) I will vote for that answer.

Comment: Your edit2 solution worked for me. I tried BadCash's approach and could not get it to work. I found that the onOptionsMenuClosed method never got called. Since the options menu is constructed programmatically, I do not have xml to play with. Since I have many options each with an icon I did not want to put any of the options in the ToolBar (ActionBar). I am using AppCompatActivity,

Answer (score 1):

Try calling `closeOptionsMenu()` before calling `finish()`:

```
closeOptionsMenu();
finish();
```

This worked for me, but there could perhaps be some sort of [race condition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition#Software) giving you problems. If so, this should work instead:

```
private boolean exit = false;


@Override
public void onOptionsMenuClosed(Menu menu) {
    super.onOptionsMenuClosed(menu);

    if( exit )
        finish();
}


@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.settings:
                // Unassigned
            return true;

        case R.id.exit:
            exit = true;
            closeOptionsMenu();
            return true;

        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hmmmm, strange indeed. Problem remains, same logcat.

Comment: Did you try setting `android:showAsAction="always"` on your exit menu item in the XML file? That should help you, but then again you might not want to have it in the action bar all the time.

Comment: I just added my menu.xml, maybe you see something I don`t

Comment: I tried your 'workaround', same issue, I don`t get it. When I exit through a normal method everything is fine.

Comment: Ok, when I apply "app:showAsAction="always" in the menu.xml it works! So what`s the problem?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/109372/discussion-between-badcash-and-simon).